# npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET but I'm not on a proxy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, proxy, npm, mean

I've been learning how to use the MEAN stack and everytime I'm following any tutorials either from a book or on github I get an absurd amount of errors whenever a run npm install.

The errors pile up so fast I can't even see what the first one is, and by the time everything finishes I can't scroll up high enough in my command line to see where it all starts. But a section of it looks like this;

```
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network  settings.
```

I have no idea how to copy out of my command line to show you more, but there are literally hundreds of errors and I don't know what any of them mean. I've tried looking up some of them, but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

After all of the errors though, everything seems to work fine. I haven't had any issues following along with tutorials and making apps.

Sorry I can't provide much more information than that, I'm new to all of this and don't really understand what's going on here. I'm pretty positive I'm not behind a proxy server and everything in my network settings seems normal to me. I honestly don't know how to tell if something is wrong with the settings, but other than running npm install, everything about my network seems fine to me.

I can't seem to find anything on the internet that relates to my issue. Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: On most operating systems you can forward the ouput of the commant to a file like so: npm install package_name > textfile.txt. Then look for a line that says: "Additional logging details can be found in" - it will point you to the location of the npm-debug.log which may contain more info.

Comment: Thank you! This gave me exactly what I needed, and I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kyrisu I figured out how to log my errors into a text file, where I was able to see the first error properly.

The error was `npm error windows_nt 6.3.9600`

After typing that into google I found this page on github
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8734

The solutions was:

```
npm uninstall -g npm
npm install -g npm@2.12.1
```

I guess I had the wrong version of npm.